# Jquery FileUpload plugin can't send formdata made up of element.value

Tags: jquery, jquery-file-upload

I'm trying to send some formdata programatically along with the file through the jquery fileupload plugin but it doesn't seem to be able to pick up data from html elements. It sends data properly if I set it to a manual string. Is this a limitation of the plugin or am I missing something?

```
$(function () {
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        formData: { name: $('input#doc_name').val() , date: "troll" },
        dataType: 'json',
        done: function (e, data) {
            $.each(data.result, function (index, file) {
                $('<p/>').text(file).appendTo(document.getElementById("bottom_right"));
            });
        },
        progressall: function (e, data) {
            var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
            $('#progress .bar').css(
            'width',
            progress + '%'
        );
        }
    });
});
```

Name comes up empty when I try to retrieve on server through Request[] but date comes up just fine.

Any help appreciated.
Raza

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: try something like `formData: { name: "'" + $('input#doc_name').val() + "'" , date: "troll" },`

Comment: Tried it in Chrome and FireFox with same results. Also tried surrounding it with quotes/spaces/characters but it just skips the element and picks up the string.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it for anyone interested. I had to put the $().fileUpload() in a method and then call that method from an onClick event. Not sure why it wouldn't work previously if anyone could enlighten us just for the sake of knowing.

```
function uploadImage() {

var x = $('#doc_name').val();
var y = $('#exp_date').val();

$('#fileupload').fileupload({
            formData: { name:x, date:y },
            dataType: 'json',
            done: function (e, data) {
                $.each(data.result, function (index, file) {
                    $('<p/>').text(file).appendTo(document.getElementById("bottom_right"));
                });
            },
            progressall: function (e, data) {
                var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
                $('#progress .bar').css(
            'width',
            progress + '%'
        );
            }
        });
}
```